# How check if the lists in a list are not empty?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of lists in Java. Here is the code:

```
List<List<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

myList.get(0).add(1);
myList.get(0).add(2);
myList.get(0).add(3);
myList.get(1).add(4);
myList.get(1).add(5);
myList.get(1).add(6);
myList.get(2).add(7);
myList.get(2).add(8);
myList.get(2).add(9);
```

Now in a part of my code I want to check if all three lists that are located in `myList` are not empty and null. Should I check each of these lists one by one, like this:

```
if (myList.get(0) != null && !myList.get(0).isEmpty()) { 
    // do something
}
```

...or is there a better and shorter way to do instead of checking one by one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use stream API for this, but also a plain loop too:

```
 boolean allNonEmptyOrNull = myList.stream()
     .allMatch(x -> x != null && !x.isEmpty());
```

Or you can check if `null` is contained or an an empty `List` for example, via:

```
System.out.println(myList.contains(null) || myList.contains(Collections.<Integer> emptyList()));
```

But this last option will break with Java 9 immutable collections, for example:

```
List.of(1, 2, 3).contains(null);
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @shmosel yes, I do

Comment: That's very surprising. Awful design decision, if you ask me.

Comment: @Eugene can we accomodate method reference in your answer?

Comment: @NisargPatil if you create a separate method, you could, since `Objects::nonNull && Predicate.not(List::isEmpty)` will not compile

Comment: How are you supposed to check if a List contains null in Java 9? Just `allMatch(x -> x != null)`?

Comment: @JollyJoker yes, but as said this *only* concerns immutable collections in java-9, `ArrayList` and the like work the same way

Comment: Not empty already implies not null so why not just `allNotEmpty` or `allHaveValues`? (also the variable is called `allNonEmptyOr(Non)Null` while the condition is `x != null` **`&&`** `!x.isEmpty()` which might be confusing for some).

Comment: @JollyJoker Immutable collections will throw an exception if you try to put a `null` in them so the fact that their method `contains` throws when called with `null` is not an issue. You can just check `if key == null` and you already know that that `key` cannot belong to a collection of that type.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta name whatever that variable you want, I could have called it `boolean b`, I guess. It matters only *how* you read it I guess, for me this variable makes perfect sense, but not everyone is me (or you). And not empty indeed implies that null checks should be done, but the OP explicitly showed that in her code, so...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta If I write a method that takes a List<Whatever> as a parameter I'll have to keep in mind that someone might call it with an immutable collection. Especially if someone else is writing unit tests. Even if I was targeting Java 8 when I wrote the original code.

Comment: Oh, [this goes back to at least 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)). "NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this collection does not support null elements (optional)". So apparently I should always have been careful with .contains

Comment: @JollyJoker exactly - if it is documented, it's not an issue, it's a documented feature.

Answer (score 9):

Using Java 7 and below this is the classical way to approach that:

```
for (List<Integer> list : myList) {
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        // do something with not empty list
    }
}
```

With Java 8 and above you can use `forEach`:

```
myList.forEach(list -> {
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        // do something with not empty list
    }
});
```

or, as already [mentioned by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52768779/2288384), with stream API you can replace `if` statement with lambda-expression:

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(list -> (list != null && !list.isEmpty()))
      .forEach(list -> {
          // do something with not empty list
      });
```

Note: all these 3 examples imply that you have initialized `myList` variable and it is not `null`, otherwise `NullPointerException` will be thrown in all snippets above.

Standard JDK does not have a quick way to check that collection is not null and not empty. But if you are using Apache `commons-collections` library, they offer such a method: [CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.util.Collection-). However, I would not recommend to add this dependency into your project just for the sake of this single function.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
boolean isEmpty = false;
for(List<Integer> list : myList) {
   if(list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
      isEmpty = true;
      break;
   }
}

if(!isEmpty) { // do your thing; }
```

Comment: First of all, you do not break early when you find an empty list, resulting in extra work. Secondly, you need to give `list` a type and use a `:` rather than `in`. Otherwise you will get a syntax error. See my answer based on the same idea.

Comment: @HackerBoss My bad. Fixed it.

Comment: Still need to give list a type for syntactical correctness. And why did I get a downvote?

Comment: @HackerBoss No idea. Voted up.

Answer (score 5):

Just check your collection not contains empty list

```
if (!L.contains(Collections.EMPTY_LIST)){ do something }
```

or empty and null check (be care with NullPointerException !!!)

```
if (!L.contains(Collections.EMPTY_LIST) && !L.contains(null)){ do something }
```

Comment: almost correct, you have to check against `null` too

Comment: Q was "are not empty". But check for null not a problem too.

Comment: you are right, but the code in the question was `myList.get(0) != null`...

Comment: and now that you have written it - it might fail if the main list is an immutable list, like java-9 has (did not downvote btw)

Answer (score 3):

```
int temp = 0;
for(int i=0;i<L.size();i++) {
    if (L.get(i).isEmpty()) {
        temp++;
    }
}
if (temp == L.size()) {
   //do what you want, all the lists inside L are empty
}
```

This is all i can think of right now.

Comment: Just use a stream.

Comment: I believe the original question was about how to work with **not empty** lists, not the opposite. Also the provided code may throw a `NullPointerException`, that original author of the question wanted to avoid

Comment: @VladimirL. you are right, all you need to use is a "!=" inside the if condition

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Java `foreach` loop. It is similar to looping by index, but reads nicer and is a bit shorter.

```
boolean nonempty = true;

for (List<Integer> list : myList) {
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
        nonempty = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This also allows you to break out early if you find an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check if all three lists that are located in list are not empty

```
myList.stream().anyMatch(List::isEmpty);
```

This should get you an output, if any inner list is empty or not.
Based on your requirement you can negate it.
But if you need to check for `null` as well, then you might try something as,

```
myList.stream().anyMatch(i -> null==i || i.isEmpty())
```

Again you can negate as required.
This answer is to add variant to the above mentioned answers.

Comment: providing the opposite of what is already answered many times, and then saying he can get what he wants by negating it, is kind of useless

Comment: No, it is a variant of what is already answered. I can't see any answer using `anyMatch`. So, you should'nt had this downvoted.